# Connect 36 UV LED board to 12 VDC source

Tags: led, voltage-source, uv

I have a UV LED board with 36 LEDs connected in series. The board's label says it works with 12 V so I tried to connect it to an AC-12 VDC converter, but it just works for a minute and then starts to blink.

I've searched about this kind of LED and it seems to work with 600-700 mA, 3-3.4 V and 3 W. I can't figure out what is happening. Do I need more source voltage or perhaps a resistor?

Can anyone help me to understand why this happens? The board is labeled for RGB LEDs, but they are all UV.

[image: source power AC to 12Vdc]

[image: it says that are RGB LEDs but all are UV LED]

ADDED DETAILS:
This was the original circuit and I want to rid of the controller, just connecting the source to the LEDs.

I also added a picture trying to show circuit paths between LEDs. It's not complete but is a general idea (the purple circle represents the 12 V path).

[image: original circuit]

[image: connection]

[image: working]

[image: purple circle represents 12V]

[image: element that want rid off]

Comment: If there's 36 of them all in series, there's *no* way it'll run on 12 V, especially not UV ones. Clarify how they're connected.

Comment: Show more of the LED board - all of it, back-side? If those are all UV LEDs, how do you know how many are working with just R+B connected? (Blinking could be overcurrent/overtemperature protection of the 24 W PS in action: even 36*1 W is too much.)

Comment: Is the LED board getting warm?  If so, what are you doing for heat sinks?

Comment: Keep a voltmeter on the power supply. Better yet, buy [a 15V voltmeter](https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-0-15V-Analog-Voltage-Voltmeter/dp/B07117Y13X) and wire it into the supply. Does anything special happen when the LEDs go out?   If you're going to make a habit of this sort of work, consider a bench power supply with adjustable voltage and current limits.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a UV LED board. It's an RGB board. And it does not consist of 36 LEDs (of any sort) connected in series. It has 3 independent channels of 12 LEDs per channel. Each channel probably consists of about 3 strings of 4 LEDs in series, the strings being in parallel. The reason your supply can't keep up is that it is only able to provide 2 amps, and the multiple parallel strings are collectively drawing too much current. Get a bigger power supply.

As a test - disconnect one of the two inputs, B or R. The board should work with a single color producing light.

Comment: `The board is labeled for RGB LEDs, but they are all UV.`

Comment: You are right WhatRoughBeats each channel is about 3 strings of 4 LEDs in series. Originally the board was connected to a component which controls effects like fading or blinking light (typical RGB cannon light for parties) and all was powered by the source shown, so I thought I  could connect directly RGB channels and rid of controller, but doesn't work.

Comment: @greybeard - Why do you think that?

Comment: @DigitalAutodidact - I suspect that the problem is that you are trying to connect your power supply directly across the LEDs. Try driving a single channel, but with a 10-ohm resistor in series. The resistor should be at least 1 watt, and even that may well get hot.

Comment: That's not what I think, that's a quote straight from the question. (I quoted that because it escaped my attention more than once…)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That's what I'm looking for, connect the power supply directly across the LEDs. I'm gonna try 10-ohm resistor in one channel

Answer (score 0):

If there really are 3 channels with 3 strings on each channel you would need 1.8 to 2.1 A for one channel. So to get all channels going at least 6.3 A would be required. I'd recommend an 8 A power supply.

Adding a series resistor to each channel might make sense if there are no resistors (?) on the LED board already.

The reason why it worked before: the RGB leds probably would not draw up to 700 mA, and also very likely had used PWM for dimming, so average current draw is often lower.

**Depending on the wavelength of the UV LEDs you should care for UV protection measures for eyes and or skin!!**

Comment: I measured the current draw in one channel and I got 1.8 A. There are not any resistor on the LED board so I'm gonna add them to each channel and try again